# Firebase database structure for one-on-one messaging?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm relatively new to Firebase and I'm trying to figure out the best way to structure my DB for 1:1 chats.

It basically has to function like Whatsapp - you have your active conversations on the left when a person sends a message that conversation is then put on top of the list and a basic one-on-one chat on the right.

Right now the best that I have got is to create a firestore "chats" collection

```
chats : {
chat : { users : [user_id, user_id], messages : {user_id, message, created_at} created_at } 
}
```

Would this solution allow me to :

- Get all the chats based on the logged-in user?
- Then Sort the returned chats by date?
- Get the latest message from the messages collection for each returned chat?
- On new message change the order of the chat and update the latest message?

And if all of that is doable would this be effective or is a there a better way?

Any help would be appreciated - thanks!

Comment: If you are interested, I have explained in one of my [tutorials](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLn2n4GESV0Ak1HiH0tTPTJXsOEy-5v9qb) how you can create a complete and functional Firestore Chat App.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How would a logged in user be associated with any given chat they participated into?

Right now your structure doesn't seem to allow for an easy handling of this, given that "user_id" are nested within the `chat` document.

Personally, here's what I would do.

First I would create 2 collections, one called `chats` one called `users`.
`users` would have the following structure:

```json
{"users": {
    "userID_1": {
        "name": "John",
        "surname": "Smith",
        "chats": [
            "chatID_1",
            "chatID_2",
            "chatID_3"
        ]
    },
    "userID_2": {
        "name": "Betty",
        "surname": "Sue",
        "chats": [
            "chatID_1",
            "chatID_4"
        ]
    }
}}
```

Chats would instead be stored like this:

```json
{"chats": {
    "chatID_1": {
        "chatName": "foo",
        "otherInfo": "..",
        "messages": {
             "messageID_1": {"senderID": "..", "message": "..", "timestamp": 999},
             "messageID_2": {"senderID": "..", "message": "..", "timestamp": 999}
        }
    },
    "chatID_2": {
        "chatName": "bar",
        "otherInfo": "..",
        "messages": {
            ...
        }
    }
}}
```

This way, when a user is logged in, you can easily fetch all his chats by querying `users.userID.chats`, and retrieve the content of any selected chat by querying `chats.chatID.messages`.

Comment: Thanks, this seems the right way to go about it and sort of aligns with an another article that I was looking into https://www.skcript.com/svr/how-to-structure-firebase-database-for-a-scalable-chat-app/

Comment: No probs, remember to upvote the answer if you liked it :) !

Comment: I know it is not explicitly stated in the question but how would this solve the requirement "retrieve first N chats preview ordered by date for the left panel (where the existing chats are displayed)"?

Comment: I am working on that scenario and the only way I figured out is to, instead of having an array of chats' ID in the user table, have a structure which contains not also the chatId but a lastMessage structure. However, this implies updating it every time there's a new message and it is not a performant (and cheap) solution in terms of db operations.

Comment: Thanks im gonna implement this if u have any sugesstion over attachment pls do add